# ttyS0 acting strangely: how to reset it without rebooting?

Tags: linux

I've got a Redhat box whose serial console (dev/ttyS0) is acting strangely. Firstly, it is echoing all input, including passwords typed at the login prompt. Secondly, running `stty sane` or other `stty` commands results in the following error:

`stty: standard input: unable to perform all requested operations`

When I press "Backspace" it gives me a ^H instead, and when I try to set this to erase via `stty erase ^H` it says: `stty: missing argument to erase`

so something is goofy and I'd like to be able to "reset" the serial console *without rebooting*. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try `reset`?

Comment: Yes, `reset` is one of the first things I tried.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. In /etc/grub.conf the kernel line contained more than one designation for console:

`console=tty0 console=ttyS0,9600 console=tty0 console=ttyS0,9600n8`

How this second pair got in there, I don't know, but because the kernel is booted with these parameters, I can't think of any way to change them on the fly, so I edited grub.conf, removed the second pair, rebooted, and the console is behaving correctly now. I assume either (a) the presence of two conflicting console directives confused the serial port, or (b) the 9600n8 by itself was inappropriate for this console device.